# Convert NaN values in 2D numpy array using values from vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a 2D numpy array and want to replace each `NaN` in each row by the corresponding value from a 1D array. For example, this matrix:

```
[[1.  2. NaN]
 [4.  5.  6.]
 [NaN NaN 9.]]
```

using vector `[3. 7. 8.]` would be converted to:

```
[[1. 2. 8.]
 [4. 5. 6.]
 [3. 7. 9.]]
```

How to do it without iterating over indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) and broadcasting:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1.,  2., np.nan],
                  [4.,  5.,  6.],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, 9.]])
>>> v = np.array([3, 7, 8])
>>> np.where(np.isnan(a), v, a)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  8.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  9.]])
```

[`numpy.isnan()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy.isnan) gives you an array of booleans with NaN having the value `True` and `False` otherwise.